# woocommerce apply coupon programmatically bug

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the code I am using:

```
if (!is_admin()):
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );
//add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'apply_matched_coupons');
//add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'apply_matched_coupons');

function apply_matched_coupons() {
global $woocommerce;
$coupon_code = 'somecodehere';

if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 1 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        wc_print_notices();
    }

}

endif;
```

The issue I am having is that when I go to the checkout page that the coupon still gets applied. It's not applied on the cart which is the desired result but I don't want it applied at all in this condition.

Any help?

Comment: I'm confused what "condition" you're talking about. Can you explain using some kind of user story, both the occurring and intended result? i.e. A user visits the cart, X happens, she then continues to checkout, Y happens, etc

Comment: @rnevius sure and Im not even sure what I am doing works because I think this is cached somehow. OK. Here is the big picture: Add a coupon code when you add to cart. However dont apply the coupon if you are a shop admin or manager on the cart or checkout page. The next stage once I know its working is to add it randomally if your not shop admin or manager but I am still working through it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your explanation, it sounds like you should be using the [`woocommerce_add_to_cart`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#948) hook, which is run when a product is successfully added to the cart. I also don't think you should be using `is_admin()`, since that just checks if you're on an admin page...not if the current user is an admin.

I would do something like the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );

function apply_matched_coupons() {
    // If the current user is a shop admin
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) return;
    // If the user is on the cart or checkout page
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) return;

    $coupon_code = 'somecodehere';

    if ( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    WC()->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
}
```

Comment: You're amazing. I can even see where things got overly complicated from my end.  Now I need to refactor to make WC()->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code ); run randomly. Thanks so much buddy.